# NHibernate map citext in postgresql

Tags: .net, postgresql, nhibernate

Does anybody know how to map string in NHibernate (via .hbm mapping) to Postgresql's "citext" type?

I tried setting sql-type="citext" like this:

```
<property name="UserName">
    <column name="username" sql-type="citext" />
</property>
```

but that doesn't work - when querying database by this column case sensitive comparison is still made.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for some time I finally found a way how to do this.
I created my own Postgresql driver by deriving from `NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver` and overriding `InitializeParameter` method. And then I configure this driver via hibernate.cfg.xml file.

I'm using Npgsql package for accessing Postgresql so idea is to overwrite NpgsqlDbType with Citext whenever I need it:

```
public class CitextPostgreSqlDriver : NpgsqlDriver
{
    protected override void InitializeParameter(DbParameter dbParam, string name, SqlType sqlType)
    {
        base.InitializeParameter(dbParam, name, sqlType);

        var dbType = sqlType?.DbType;
        var npgsqlParam = dbParam as Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter;
        if (npgsqlParam != null && (dbType == System.Data.DbType.String || dbType == System.Data.DbType.AnsiString))
        {
            npgsqlParam.ResetDbType();
            npgsqlParam.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Citext;
        }
    }
}
```